# VBA: Word 2013 Expand/Collapse Specific Headings

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need help, and I think this is pretty easy if you know VBA:

I want to have a button or dropdown menu that expands/collapses specific menu headings.

Here is an outline of the layout of the document (there are menus and data within the Department levels as well, but I don't need to collapse/expand those levels):

### - Daily Processes

- Department A
- Department B
- Department C
- Department D

### - Weekly Processes

- Department A
- Department B
- Department C
- Department D

### - Monthly Processes

- Department A
- Department B
- Department C
- Department D

### - Annual Processes

- Department A
- Department B
- Department C
- Department D

### - Appendix

I want there to be buttons for each department, hiding all other departments.  For example, if I click Department A, all Dept B, C, D menus will collapse, only showing Dept A.

I would imagine these would be the buttons that I would need:

1. ExpandAll
2. ShowDeptA
3. ShowDeptB
4. ShowDeptC
5. ShowDeptD

This is the pseudocode for one dept that I think would work:

1. ExpandAll
2. Start at top of Document
3. Search Format=Heading2
4. If Heading2=DepartmentA: expand heading,
    Else: collapse heading

What I have so far:  (All I need the command to collapse headings)

```
Sub OpenDeptA()
'
' OpenDeptA Macro
' Show only DeptA sections
'
'    Expand all menus
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ExpandAllHeadings
'    Move cursor to the top
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
'    Find first menu using format: Heading 2
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
    Selection.Find.Execute
'    Loop through document collapsing heading if not equal to "DeptA"
Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
    If Selection.Text = "DeptA" Then
        Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
        Selection.Find.Execute
    Else: Selection.CollapseHeading  ***NOT SURE HOW TO COLLAPSE MENUS***
        Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")            
        Selection.Find.Execute
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: the thing is that we don't write code for free here. We provide support if you have already tried something on your own. So, have you?

Comment: you can always re-edit  your question instead of adding comments which are difficult to read.

Comment: can anyone help me on this?

Comment: the thing is that you are wrong in your first sentence in your question where you write: `I think this is pretty easy if you know VBA`. Indeed, it isn't so easy...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Word 2013, so I can't provide a complete answer. But I can help with two aspects of what you are doing.

1. Comparing text. Right now you are comparing just words "Dept A", but it is likely that the actual selection contains the line break as well. You could try

   ```
   Selection.Text = "DeptA" & vbCR
   ```

   or

   ```
   Selection.Text Like "DeptA*"
   ```

   It depends a bit on how tightly controlled those headings are.
2. Collapsing the content. <del>I assume you are already putting the document into Outline View. If so, the command is</del>

   <del>ActiveWindow.View.CollapseOutline Selection.Range</del>

   <del>the thing about CollapseOutline, though, is that it only collapses by one level. So if you had a Heading 3 under your Heading 2, that would be collapsed but your Heading 2 would not be. From what I can tell there's no harm in running CollapseOutline several times, so I'd work out ahead of time how deeply the levels in your document go and then run the method enough times to accommodate that.</del>
   Ok, revisiting this with a copy of Word 2013 in front of me. There doesn't seem to be a method for collapsing the text; instead, you set its collapsed state to true. And, it works on paragraphs, not ranges or selections. So here is the final portion of your code, with the collapsing code included:

   ```
   Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
       If Selection.Text Like "Department A*" Then
           Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
           Selection.Find.Execute
       Else: Selection.Paragraphs(1).CollapsedState = True
           Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
           Selection.Find.Execute
       End If
   Loop
   ```

As to your question about Word Commands that you can see in the Macros list, you can run these, but their real power lies in the ability to recode them to do what you prefer. In this case what you need to do is supported by the object model so I wouldn't bother with them.

Lastly, if you intend to do a lot of VBA coding, I'd recommend getting familiar with the Object Browser (F2 from the VB Editor). You can search for something you think might exist there; for instance, in looking into this question I searched for "Collapseheading". In this case that wasn't fruitful on its own, but it did put me in the neighborhood of CollapsedState.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Christina.  Comparing the text works now.  I am not using outline view, is there a command to collapse a heading in the default view, or should I use outline mode?  Under macros, I see one listed under "word commands" that is called "CollapseHeading", could this be what I'm looking for?  If so, how do I call this built-in macro?

Comment: The default keyboard shortcut is Alt+Shift+- or Alt+Shift+Num-.  I tried to record a macro for this shortcut, and nothing shows up in the  VBA editor.  I just need a way to call this in my code, and I think I am done..

Comment: I'm not sure about CollapseHeading, that may be a Word 2013 command as I don't have it. I do have OutlineCollapse, which is the Word Command equivalent of CollapseOutline. I'm not sure what it would mean to collapse headings outside of Outline view, though. Again, I don't use Word 2013 every day, but based on my experience with it you would still need to be in outline view for this to actually do anything. I'll try to edit my post tomorrow with a short subroutine that illustrates how this would work in Outline View.

Comment: this is a new feature in Word 2013.  Is there a way to simply call a built-in word command on a selection?  I have tried to record it, and nothing shows up in the VBE.  Take a look at the new feature:  [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/collapse-or-expand-parts-of-a-document-HA102840146.aspx)

Comment: So, serves me right for trying to answer a question without having the right version of Word. Edited my answer to address the 2013 object model. Ignore what I said about Outline View.